# Is it possible to generate facelets code from UiComponent Object in JSFManagedBean

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, java-ee-6, uicomponents

I want to generate facelets code from UIComponent,
Eg:

```
org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButton;

CommandButton btn=new CommandButton();
btn.setValue("Click");
```

for this code, the following tag has to be generated

```
<p:commandButton value="Click" />
```

what i need is to generate facelet code corresponding to UIComponent object in the bean and code has to be stored and used later.

is it possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at these two articles [1] and [2]. You have to locate the parent component to which you want to attach your new components, create the components and add them as children. Here [3] is an example on how to locate components by id.

[1] - http://www.softwareengineeringsolutions.com/thoughts/frameworks/JSF.Techniques-Adding.Components.Dynamically.htm

[2] - http://www.jsfcentral.com/articles/dynamic_jsf.html

[3] - http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/02/jsf-working-with-component-ids.html

Answer (score 1):

Used Binding

```
<p:commandButton value="Click" binding="#{beanName.btn}" />
```

Comment: what i need is to generate facelet code corresponding to UIComponent object in the bean and code has to be stored and used later.